# How to make a new sentence from 「母が私に卵を食べさせた。」where 卵 must be the subject?

Tags: passive-voice

> A: 母が私に卵を食べさせた。My mother forced me to eat eggs.
>
> B: 私が母に卵を食べさせられた。I have been forced to eat eggs by my mother.

Now I want to make the eggs as the subject. How to make this sentence in Japanese?
My attempt is as follows, but I am not sure whether it is correct grammatically.

> C1: 卵が母に私を食べさせられた。

## Edit:

My second attempt is as follows.

> C2: 卵は母に食べさせられた私に食べられた。

Comment: Can you make such a sentence in English without changing the meaning?

Comment: @naruto The closest thing I can come up with is, "The eggs were force-fed to me by my mother." I doubt it could be done with the word "eat."

Answer (score 2):

The sentence C doesn't make sense. I think a direct object can't become a subject in a causative sentence.

For example, 私は、彼に車を運転させた and 彼は、私に車を運転させられた make sense but 車は、運転させた and 車は、運転させられた doesn't make sense.